# Load Data and Update Existing View D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am attempting to update the SVG with alternate CSV data. If i try to reinitialise everything, and essentially do the same thing outside of the updateDate(), it does not work. Below is the Javascript script I have written. I am a beginner and am following examples from Mike Blostock's blog, I appreciate all help.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
margin = {right: 50, left: 50},
width = +svg.attr("width") ,
height = +svg.attr("height");

var format = d3.format(",d");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([width, height])
    .padding(1.5);

d3.csv("flare.csv", function(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  if (d.value) return d;
}, function(error, classes) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var root = d3.hierarchy({children: classes})
      .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
      .each(function(d) {
        if (id = d.data.id) {
          var id, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
          d.id = id;
          d.package = id.slice(0, i);
          d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
        }
      });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack(root).leaves())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y +     ")"; });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.package); });

  node.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return "clip-" + d.id; })
    .append("use")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#" + d.id; });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d.id + ")"; })
    .selectAll("tspan")
    .data(function(d) { return d.class.split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g); })
    .enter().append("tspan")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", function(d, i, nodes) { return 13 + (i - nodes.length / 2 - 0.5) * 10; })
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id + "\n" + format(d.value); });
});

function updateData() {
    console.log("clicked");

// I know I need to reRead the new CSV File called "flarealt.csv"--- 
//But I do not know how to update the SVG ON Screen

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting your question, but it sounds like the user clicks a button, which triggers a change to different CSV source data, but the same drawing action occurs.

If so, I would suggest the following:

(Note: this is all untested pseudo-code. If you create a plunkr for your code we can be exact)

Create an "update" function, which is a named function for the code currently handled by `function(d)`. IE:

`function update(d) { 
  d.value = +d.value;
  ...
}`

Convert your initial code to :
`d3.csv("flare.csv", update(d) );`

Create the change capability. Something like:
`function changeDataSource() { d3.csv("flareAlt.csv", update(d) ) ); }`

Connect your button to the above function. `<button onClick="changeDataSource()">Switch to FlareAlt</button>`

Comment: You are correctly interpreting my question. Unfortunately, the psedo code is not enough for me to correct my problem. Can you provide actual code example?

Comment: If you start a plunkr (http://plnkr.co/), the stack community is more likely to contribute to it. It makes sure we don't do too much work (we're lazy :)

Comment: Okay I will do that.